# Unable to Adjust Size for pdf in Preview

Tags: pdf, preview

As shown in the screenshot the "Adjust Size" is disabled and grayed-out for the given PDF:

[image: Preview > Tools > Adjust Size...]

So how do we reduce the size of a pdf in preview (or even skim?)

Comment: Try making a selection on the PDF, then try ⌘K to crop?

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry  cropping selects  a portion of the pdf but does not resize the selection. The intent here is to retain the (entire) selection and reduce its resolution

Comment: Ah, I understand. You want to *scale* the image. Like Dictionarics Anonymous indicated, Preview only does this on images and not PDFs.

Comment: @javadba  did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not find out how to do this in preview or skim: so a "real" answer would still be awarded.

However there is a workaround when printing: the print dialog for my HP laserjet has a "Scale" that can be applied. This took care of my immediate need.

[image]

Comment: This was the most useful for me too.

Answer (score 4):

The Adjust Size / Colour feature in Preview doesn't work for PDF files, only for bitmap image files. Usually you don't want to change the format of a PDF document, anyway.

However, if you have a PDF file that contains only embedded bitmap images, and you want a downsized version of that image, it's possible to use the Preview's export feature: **File > Export**. The export dialog will ask for a pixel density (in ppi) to use for the export, as it is assumed that you are converting vector graphics/text to bitmap graphics…

Another possibility is to use the marquee/selection tool to select an area or the whole page and press Cmd-C, then create a new Preview document from the selected area by pressing Cmd-N, and save the new document in a bitmap format.

I can't say what it does to the exported image if you put in a ppi value different from the actual ppi value of the embedded image. There are commercially sold third-party tools that extract bitmap images from PDFs without resampling them, e.g. Acrobat Pro/DC and others. A smaller and free tool is downloadable via SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdf-images/

Comment: Thanks - those are probably the only options. They are not adequate for my particular circumstances. However I am going to upvote (though not accept) anyways - since your points are valid and probably helpful to others reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me in Mac OS X 10.13 (High Sierra):

1. Open PDF to shrink in Preview
2. Select File -> Export
3. Leave format as "PDF". In "Quartz Filter" select: "Reduce File Size"
4. In "Export as", I changed the file-name e.g. added "_small"; so I don't overwrite the original.
5. Press on "Save"

You don't have any control on scaling parameters, but results were good enough for what I needed.

Comment: The question is how to reduce the physical dimensions of a PDF, not how to reduce the file size. File Size reduction has been dealt with in other questions.